# Implementing an ActionResult across all Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and trying to get my head around Controllers.  Please could you comment on the following scenario?:

It is a business requirement of our application that users must accept a "privacy policy" screen when using the application.  I do this by setting a cookie when the user clicks a link in the initial Home controller index view.

But, I need to make sure that any entry point in our application (i.e not just from the index page but anywhere in the application) checks for the existence of the cookie.  It makes sense to me that the value could be checked by each controller, but I don't want to duplicate the same "If cookie exists do something" code on each controller.  So is there a next level up I can write my method?

Hoping this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom base controller (that itself inherits the standard ASP.NET MVC controller) that contains your cookie verification code, then have your other controllers derive from that.

For instance, to make sure all my actions by default require a user to be authenticated, I use something similar to this as a base controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class CoreController : Controller
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Then my home controller looks like:

```
public class HomeController : CoreController
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I like both approaches suggested here but I implemented yours first.  Thank you for your comments (I can't believe I overlooked something so simple!)

Comment: You could combine both approaches; add the attribute to the core/base controller if every action needs to do the cookie verification. One thought, though: you could make acceptance of the privacy policy a condition of authentication, and then just use the normal authorization pattern that ASP.NET MVC follows.

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom ActionFilterAttribute.

**Create a class CheckCookie:**

```
public class CheckCookie : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!CookieExists)// Check the Cookie exists
            {
                //Redirect if the cookie does not exists
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Redirect/NoCookie");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[CheckCookie]//Check the Cookie exists
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Going to have to go read about ActionFilters - this answer sounds like an interesting way to solve the problem.  Thank you for your comments!